# Get Unauthorized error on React app ONLY after first login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, authorization

I implemented a fullstack React and Spring Boot app and I use Spring Security for authentication and authorization. There is a weird behavior regarding to the authorization.

Whenever I restart the frontend application via `npm start` and login to the app, all the necessary parameters e.g. userId, jwt, roles, username are set to localStorage properly and the app navigates Home page that does not need authorization. **However**, when I click on a menu that requires authorization, I get "Full authentication is required to access this resource" error.

BUT, if I refresh the page after login, via `window.location.reload()` on the home page, and then click a menu, there is no error (if I first navigate to a page instead of home the error occurs in a short time before refresh).

I tried the same endpoint many times via Postman and there is not any problem like this. For this reason, it seems to be that there is something missing on React side. Do you have any idea?

Here is my headers sent via Axios, but I think it is ok:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    // "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}`
  },
};
```

***service.js***

```
import axios from "./axios";

const headers = {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers,
});

export default axiosInstance;

axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("tokenKey")}`;

export const getWithAuth = (url) => {
  const request = axiosInstance.get(url);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};
```

Comment: `const AUTH_TOKEN = localStorage.getItem("tokenKey");`, but actually token is also ok. It is really weird that, if I refresh the page, nothing is changed and the jwt will be same before and after refresh.

Comment: I added, if you need I can also share routes on App.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why when you first login you get `unauthorize` but when you refresh it works fine ?

- This is because when the file first loaded it didn't find `tokenKey` in localStorage, however when you login the `tokenKey` will be stored in the localStorage and when you refresh you get the token.

How to solve this ?

**service.js** :

```
import axios from "axios";
const headers = {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers,
});
export default axiosInstance;
```

Then you should set the `tokenKey` returned from the login request in axios.

```
axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokenKey}`;
```

Also you can get rid of the `getWithAuth` function, juste use `axiosInstance` in any request:

```
export const login = async (credentials) => {
  let data;
  try {
  const response = await axiosInstance.post(`/auth/login`, {
    email: credentials?.email,
    password: credentials?.password,
  });
  const token = response?.data?.token
  axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  localStorage.setItem('tokenKey', token)
    //...
  } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying now. Just for confirmation >>>

Comment: **1.** `axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokenKey}`; should be used with `AUTH_TOKEN` instead of `tokenKey`, right?

Comment: Should be the name stored in localStorage

Comment: **2.** What about the methods that is using `config` parameter e.g. `getWithAuth` method? Should I pass `axiosInstance` instead of `config` parameter?

Comment: When I use `axiosInstance` instead of config, it does not worked.

Comment: can you show me how you implemented this `axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization`

Comment: no, you should put `axiosInstance.defaults...` in the login request, after you get the token set it in the `axiosInstance.defaults...` and in the localStorage

Comment: What about the headers?  Should I use all the headers in the config section in my question?

Comment: remove the Authorization from config

Comment: I think I found the problem. Could you pls look at my last update (Update II)? Even if it does not redirect Unauthorized page, the code hits that line and I think I cannot check if the user has a role in the related url (actually he has). Here is the problematic line: `return !roles.length || roles.some(r => userRoles.includes(r))` So, how should I check if the `roles` has any role in `userRoles`?